# Can a template class be used as argument to a template function specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template function:

```
template <class T>
inline T ParseValueFromJson(const JSONValue& jsonValue);
```

Which is in turn used in other template functions, for example:

```
template <class T>
bool TryGetValueFromJson(
    const JSONValue& jsonValue,
    const String& name,
    T& variable)
{
    if (!jsonValue.Contains(name))
    {
        return false;
    }

    variable = ParseValueFromJson<T>(jsonValue[name]);
    return true;
}
```

Now I want to specialize ParseValueFromJson for a number of different types, and one of them is a template class (Vector). However using a typical specialization would mean the type parameter to Vector would be undefined:

```
template <>
inline Vector<T> ParseValueFromJson<Vector<T>>(const JSONValue& jsonValue)
```

Besides which, in the function implementation I would need the type of T because I'd be using the T typed version of ParseValueFromJson to parse individual items.

And of course if I use template T in the specialization, it is a different function that results in ambiguous calls:

```
    template <typename T>
inline Vector<T> ParseValueFromJson<Vector<T>>(const JSONValue& jsonValue)
```

So is this possible, or do I need to settle for a separate TryGetContainerFromJson (or similar) function that takes the templated collection type as a second template parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would opt for a implementation `serializer` template struct that deals with the serialization *(and that can be easily partially specialized)*, as [template function specialization can be troublesome](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

```
// Default serializer implementation.
namespace impl
{
    template <typename T>
    struct serializer 
    {
        T from_json(const JSONValue& jv)
        { 
            // default implementation...
        }
    };
}

// Convenient interface function.
template <class T>
inline T ParseValueFromJson(const JSONValue& jsonValue)
{
    return impl::serializer<T>{}.from_json(jsonValue);
}

// "Special" serializer implementations.
namespace impl
{            
    template <typename T>
    struct serializer<Vector<T>>
    {
        Vector<T> from_json(const JSONValue& jv)
        { 
            Vector<T> result;
            for(auto c : jv.children()) 
            {
                result.add(ParseValueFromJson<T>(c));
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link on function specialization. I was leaning towards @Smeeheey's solution, but given that I'll probably reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot partially specialize function templates ([obligatory link to Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)), but you can always overload function templates. Just forward along your primary, passing the type as a tag parameter:

```
template <class > struct tag { };

template <class T>
inline T ParseValueFromJson(const JSONValue& jsonValue) {
    return impl::ParseValueFromJson(jsonValue, tag<T>{});
}
```

And then provide a bunch of overloads:

```
namespace impl {    
    template <class T>
    inline T ParseValueFromJson(const JSONValue& jsonValue, tag<T> ) {
        // generic, if that makes sense
    }

    template <class T>
    inline T ParseValueFromJson(const JSONValue& jsonValue, tag<std::vector<T>> ) {
        // vector version
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't partially specialize a function, however you certainly can overload it, including with another templated function. This works:

```
template <typename T>
void func(const T& arg)
{
    std::cout << "General" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void func(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::cout << "Vector overload" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    func(1);                   //outputs "General"
    func(std::vector<int>{1}); //outputs "Vector overload"

    return 0;
}
```

In your case, you could adapt this solution if you're happy to return by output parameter, so then you have 2 functions like this:

```
template <class T>
inline void ParseValueFromJson(const JSONValue& jsonValue, T& output);

template <class T>
inline void ParseValueFromJson(const JSONValue& jsonValue, std::vector<T>& output);
```

That actually works well with your code, as you already ultimately return the answer by output parameter. So at your call site, you just change the line

```
variable = ParseValueFromJson<T>(jsonValue[name]);
```

to

```
ParseValueFromJson<T>(jsonValue[name], variable);
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use tag dispatching to keep the return-by-value.

Comment: I'm quite happy to use an output parameter in this case. Out of interest why does this work, vs the return value?

Comment: Function overloads are not allowed to differ only by return value type

Comment: You could certainly have them return your required value instead, as long as there was some other parameter to distinguish the overload signatures (which you don't have in your case). As TartanLlama points out this could be alternatively achieved by tag dispatch.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks, out params are perfectly fine here :)
Once I've had a chance to test run it, I'll select the answer.

Comment: Would the downvoter please point out what they're unhappy about?

Comment: I don't think so. The moral of that article is that you shouldn't specialize template functions, use overloading instead - which is exactly what I'm doing. There is no specialization in the above code.